# Swift 4 Align attributed text to center in label

Tags: ios, uilabel, swift4

How to align AttributedText in center?

1. Text is downloaded from API
2. Label heigh is dynamic
3. None of Xcode settings had effect
4. code so far:

   ```
   extension String {
   var atributedText: NSMutableAttributedString {
   let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
   style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center

   guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return NSMutableAttributedString() }
   guard let attrStr = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
                       data: data,
                       options: [NSMutableAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSMutableAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
                       documentAttributes: nil)
       else { return NSMutableAttributedString() }

   attrStr.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length))
   return attrStr
    }
   }
   ```
5. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxWTZ.png)

Extension did text in center but vertically, but how to align vertically and horizontally? Thank you.

Comment: I believe this is working for me. Are you sure you are using `UILabel` and not `UITextView`? If you are using label could you try manipulating constraints so that the label is in center of your view and uses intrinsic size. You will need to setup constraints for leading, trailing, center vertically, top>0, bottom>0.

Comment: Yes i'm sure it is UILabel. And constraints are left: 0 right: 0 , bottom: 5, top : 100 if image is not loaded then top: 5

Comment: I'm so desperate i can't find any solution... Is the way how to debug textLabel? To get any value if text centered?

Answer (score 0):

I found mistake i did. I didn't setup label.bottom to cell.bottom constraint. So when i changed my top constraint to 5, label always went to top, and doesn't expanded